# Flask website hosted over SSL not working in any microsoft browser (Edge or IE) but works in any other browser

Tags: python, apache, internet-explorer, ssl, flask

I have three different python flask apps hosted on Apache using WSGI Flup webserver over FastCGI.

I am able to access all of the apps without any issues using any non-microsoft browser. Out of the three apps, two are just for services and return only json data while the third app houses our website. All the three apps are SSL enabled and can be accessed only through SSL.

The problem I am facing is that any version of Microsoft edge or IE is unable to open the flask app which serves the website, at all.
The error that I am getting in IE says that it is a DNS error. When I checked my Apache access logs, I found out that the hit by IE or edge is not even logged there. The logs appear though when I hit my other two JSON data returning flask apps through microsoft browsers.

The two apps which return only JSON data are working flawlessly in the Microsoft browsers as well as they are working in Chrome, Safari etc.

What can be the reason for the microsoft browsers to not be able to access only one flask app but render the other two over SSL considering that all is fine when the same is accessed through any other browser?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

P.S. - I have checked the settings of all the three flask apps, and all the three are configured in the same manner without any discrepancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the problem was with favicon.ico file. Microsoft's browsers including Edge actively look for it on the server or web app root folder, and in case it doesn't exist, they simply refuse to display the page without giving out a proper error message.

The problem was solved by adding the favicon file through the method mentioned here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/favicon/